# How to create file inside the configuration folder of IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I know that in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS this configuration folder named **.IdeaIC14**. It could be in any path, depends on installation properties and user's operating system. Is there any way I can get the path to this folder from my intellij plugin to create some files in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an IntelliJ plugin, you can get the path by calling `PathManager.getConfigPath()`.

In a program that runs outside of IntelliJ IDEA, this is not possible in the general case. On Linux, IntelliJ IDEA determines the actual path to the configuration file by reading `bin/idea.properties` in the IntelliJ IDEA installation directory, which could be any path (IntelliJ IDEA is installed by unpacking a tar.gz archive, so there is no standard installation location).

Comment: Really? Because I found out that I can get the path by System.getPropery("idea.config.path").

Comment: You can call this method from an IntelliJ plugin. Your question talks about "my java program". If your Java program is an IntelliJ plugin, you should say so in your question.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that.